# How to disable TinyMce cdn for one textarea?

Tags: python, django, tinymce

I'm using TinyMce as cdn how do I disable for a specific textarea.

I see everyone is explaining to do the bellow code but I'm using as cdn.

```
tinyMCE.init({
    ...
    editor_deselector : "mceNoEditor"
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `editor_deselector:` configuration option was depreciated starting with TinyMCE 4.x.

Tiny's `selector` option utilizes CSS selector syntax to target elements for the editor. Consequently, you can use the `:not()` pseudo-class to achieve the behavior you are looking for:

```
    selector: "textarea:not(.not-here)",
```

Here is a Tiny Fiddle Example:
http://fiddle.tinymce.com/xdhaab

And here's some more info on `:not()`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not